# Ideas to write better if statements

Tags: coding-style, if-statement, readability

In this question I just want to ask for some ideas. I sometimes run into situations where I end up writing such `if` statements, however, I feel like there's a better way to write this as `func1()` is written in two places, I believe it should be only in one place.

```
if (cond1) {
    func1();
} else {
    if (cond2) {
        func1();
    } else {
        func2();
    }
}
```

How would you write this in a better, and of course readable way?

Answer (score 3):

You've not said what language, but it looks C/Java/C# based...

```
if (cond1 || cond2) {
    func1();
} else {
    func2();
}
```

or similar should work?

Comment: You beat me to this answer. However I was going to note that the approach is not necessarily generalisable.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if ((cond1)||(cond2))
{
  func1();
}
else
{
  func2();
}
```